# How do I assign functions for cartesian coordinates and rotations to irreducible representations of a character table?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, symmetry, group-theory

I do not really understand the intuition behind the functions assigned to irreducible representations.
For example, in H₂O, the A₂ representation is given by

```
E   C₂   σv(xz)   σv(yz)
1   -1    1       -1
```

and the associated linear functions are x and Ry, but I am not sure where these come from.

Comment: Since 5 months have gone by with no answers or comments, I think it's fair to let you know about [Matter Modeling Stack Exchange](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) which also answers group theory questions, but make sure to delete the question from here if you're cross-posting there (or to at least put a note at the top of your question, saying that it's cross-posted).